# Trying to fadein divs in a sequence, over time, using JQuery

Tags: jquery, queue, fadein, sequential

I'm trying to figure out how to make 4 images fade in sequentially when the page loads.

The following is my (amateurish) code:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="outercorners">

 <img id="corner1" src="images/corner1.gif" width="6" height="6" alt=""/>
 <img id="corner2" src="images/corner2.gif" width="6" height="6" alt=""/>
 <img id="corner3" src="images/corner3.gif" width="6" height="6" alt=""/>
 <img id="corner4" src="images/corner4.gif" width="6" height="6" alt=""/> 

</div><!-- end #outercorners-->
```

Here is the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#corner1").fadeIn("2000", function(){

$("#corner3").fadeIn("4000", function(){

  $("#corner2").fadeIn("6000", function(){

    $("#corner4").fadeIn("8000", function(){


    });

   });

 });

 });
```

Here is the css:

```
#outercorners {
position: fixed;
top:186px;
left:186px;
width:558px;
height:372px;
}

#corner1 {
position: fixed;
top:186px;
left:186px;
display: none;
}

#corner2 {
position: fixed;
top:186px;
left:744px;
display: none;
}

#corner3 {
position: fixed;
top:558px;
left:744px;
display: none;
}

#corner4 {
position: fixed;
top:558px;
left:186px;
display: none;
}
```

They seem to just wink at me, rather than fade in in the order I've ascribed to them. Should I be using the queue() function? And, if so, how would I implement it in this case?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the quotations away from your durations or use one of the presets 'slow' or 'fast' etc

```
$("#corner1").fadeIn(2000, function(){...
```

OR

```
$("#corner1").fadeIn("slow", function(){...
```

NOT

```
$("#corner1").fadeIn("2000", function(){...
```

Comment: the strings equate to 1 and not the value, slow = 600 and fast =200 and default = 400

Comment: Thank you -  that's really handy to know!

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a couple of months old question but I just thought to post a solution which might help someone. I would do something like this:

```
var d= 0;
$('#outercorners > img').each(function() {
    $(this).delay(d).fadeIn(1000);
    d += 1000;
});
```

You can change the 1000ms to any figure to suit your need. Note that they don't have to be equal.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/e5H5Y/

http://jsfiddle.net/e5H5Y/2/

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you've got many images, then you might want to fade them in with a timed function:

```
var x=0; // The corner counter

function fading() {
  $("#corner"+(++x)).fadeIn(2000); // Fade in the current corner

  if (x==4) { // Last image to be faded in?
    clearInterval(); // Stop interval
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval("fading()",1000); // Call function every second
});
```

Comment: Ah - thank you for this too. I figured there must be a more elegant way to write the code. As a beginner I tend to understand things better by writing it all out longhand. But your comments on the above code are much appreciated. I'll try this out!

Comment: No problem. Learning is a fun process. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap your images in a `<div>` and fade those. Like:

```
<div id="corner1"><img src="images/corner1.gif" width="6" height="6" alt=""/></div>
```

The quotes around the numbers shouldn't make a difference. JS will implicitly change "2000" to 2000 in a context where a number is expected (except when using +, which will concat strings).

Comment: "The quotes around the numbers shouldn't make a difference" Not so - http://jsbin.com/ebiga/edit

Comment: Touché *shakes fist at jsbin*